# Transfer list of dictionaries from python to json file

Tags: python, json, dataset

I have a list of dictionaries in python with the format:

```
[{key1a: value1a, key2a: values2a}, {key1b: value1b, key2b: values2b}, ...]
```

I need to create a json file with the format:

Line 1: `{key1a: value1a, key2a: values2a}`

Line 2: `{key1b: value1b, key2b: values2b}`
...

I know that I can write json files with:

```
with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data_json, outfile)
```

But I need the exact format I described, without ',' separation between lines and [..] brackets.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for but here it is:

```
s = [{"key1a": "value1a", "key2a": "values2a"}, {"key1b": "value1b", "key2b": "values2b"}]

with open("data.json", "w+") as f:
    for i in s:
        json.dump(i, f)
        f.write("\n")
```